# not recording or retrieving the data

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

For some reason i am not able to retrieve and/or place any data using IndexedDB method... Is the code wrong or i am missing something ?

I placed already several console.log's and i have already add or tried to add new values but it's say's that have added them (or at least the successfully message popup but nothing comes out into the console log with the result's...

```
let newDataLine = [{ name: name.value}];

let transaction = db.transaction( ["permit"], "readwrite");

transaction.oncomplete = function() {
statusText.textContent = 'Something was just added';
console.log('-------transaction.oncomplete----------')
console.log(objectStore);

// update the display of data to show the newly added item, by running displayData() again.
displayData();
};

transaction.onerror = function() {
status.textContent = 'Error reading/writing data from/into db error ' + transaction.error;
}

// call an object store that's already been added to the database
let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("permit");

let objectStoreRequest = objectStore.add(newDataLine[0]);

objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
statusText.textContent = 'New permit was just added';
console.log('-------objectStoreRequest.onsuccess----------')
console.log(objectStore);
}
```

full code at https://jsfiddle.net/m7nx9a3v/

The idea was to place, retrieve and populate the data to the table...
Thanks in advance

Comment: insertion into db works. checked

Comment: Note: IndexedDB API is powerful, but may seem too complicated for simple cases. If you'd prefer a simple API, try libraries such as localForage, dexie.js, ZangoDB, PouchDB, idb, idb-keyval and JsStore that make IndexedDB more programmer-friendly. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API]

Comment: kindly try out my answer

Comment: Hi... i will mate ... just wake up lool, still see a little fuzzy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function displayData() {
      let objectStore = db.transaction('permit').objectStore('permit');

      objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
            dataLine.innerHTML+= '<tr><td>'+cursor.value.name+'</td><td class="buttons"></td></tr>';
          console.log(
            'Name for key ' + cursor.key + ' is ' + cursor.value.name
          );
          cursor.continue();
        } else {
          console.log('No more entries!');
        }
      };
    }
```

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: ohh so issue was with how i was retrieving the data from the internal db... I see now. thanks. Having now a different issue but will check it in 20m